# Change columns values depending on others df values in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Hello I have a **df1** :

```
scaf_name       coordinates value    
JZSA01000001.1  1   2
JZSA01000001.1  2   2
JZSA01000001.1  3   2
JZSA01000001.1  4   2
JZSA01000001.1  5   2
JZSA01000001.1  6   2
JZSA01000001.1  7   2
JZSA01000001.1  8   2
JZSA01000001.1  9   2
JZSA01000001.1  10  2
JZSA01000001.1  11  5
JZSA01000001.1  12  5
JZSA01000001.1  13  5
JZSA01000001.1  14  5
JZSA01000001.1  15  5
JZSA01000001.1  16  5
JZSA01000001.1  17  5
JZSA01000001.1  18  6
JZSA01000002.1  1   2
JZSA01000002.1  2   2
JZSA01000002.1  3   2
JZSA01000002.1  4   2
JZSA01000002.1  5   2
JZSA01000002.1  6   2
JZSA01000003.1  1   5
JZSA01000003.1  2   5
JZSA01000003.1  3   6
JZSA01000003.1  4   6
JZSA01000003.1  5   6
JZSA01000003.1  6   6
JZSA01000003.1  7   6
JZSA01000003.1  8   6
JZSA01000003.1  9   6
```

and another **df_interval**

```
scaffold          start     end
JZSA01000001.1_0  1         14
JZSA01000001.1_1  15        18
JZSA01000002.1    1         12
JZSA01000003.1_0  1         3
JZSA01000003.1_1  4         6
JZSA01000003.1_2  7         9
```

and I would like to change the `df1$scaf_name` according to the `df1$scaf_name$start` and `df1$scaf_name$end`

so for instance

every `df1$scaf_name` containing `df_interval$scaffold`  and where `df1$coordinates` os between `1-14` would be named `JZSA01000001.1_0`

Here I should get as output

```
scaf_name       coordinates value    
JZSA01000001.1_0    1   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    2   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    3   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    4   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    5   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    6   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    7   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    8   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    9   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    10  2
JZSA01000001.1_0    11  5
JZSA01000001.1_0    12  5
JZSA01000001.1_0    13  5
JZSA01000001.1_0    14  5
JZSA01000001.1_1    15  5
JZSA01000001.1_1    16  5
JZSA01000001.1_1    17  5
JZSA01000001.1_1    18  6
JZSA01000002.1      1   2
JZSA01000002.1      2   2
JZSA01000002.1      3   2
JZSA01000002.1      4   2
JZSA01000002.1      5   2
JZSA01000002.1      6   2
JZSA01000003.1_0    1   5
JZSA01000003.1_0    2   5
JZSA01000003.1_0    3   6
JZSA01000003.1_1    4   6
JZSA01000003.1_1    5   6
JZSA01000003.1_1    6   6
JZSA01000003.1_2    7   6
JZSA01000003.1_2    8   6
JZSA01000003.1_2    9   6
```

The df1 file is very huge, if someone have and idea to be the fastest possible it would be amazing.
Thank you

DATA

**df1**

```
structure(list(scaf_name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("JZSA01000001.1", 
"JZSA01000002.1", "JZSA01000003.1"), class = "factor"), coor = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L), dinates.value = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-33L))
```

**df_interval**

```
structure(list(scaffold = structure(1:6, .Label = c("JZSA01000001.1_0", 
"JZSA01000001.1_1", "JZSA01000002.1", "JZSA01000003.1_0", "JZSA01000003.1_1", 
"JZSA01000003.1_2"), class = "factor"), start = c(1L, 15L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 7L), end = c(14L, 18L, 12L, 3L, 6L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use a non-equi join from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df_interval, scaf_name := scaffold,
         on =  .(coordinates >= start, coordinates <= end)]
```

Comment: it is wierd I tried with another data set and it works except for a particular scaf_name  wich is not present in the finale output, would you have na idea ?